# Passing image data to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, mobile

I'm trying to access a camera and a photo album on a mobile device and get the chosen image. I did that with the code below. My problem is, it generates image data, and I have to transfer that to another page, but because of the size of the generated string, I can't use URL parameters. It shows me the error: `[404] Request-URI Too long`. How can I pass the information to the other page?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/8u426/

The JS:

```
<script>

    oFReader = new FileReader();

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {     
        document.getElementById("fotoImg").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("fotoImg").style.visibility = "visible"; 
        var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
        screenHeight = screenHeight - 220;
        document.getElementById("fotoImg").style.height = screenHeight;
        document.getElementById("stringImg").innerText = "Data Image: " + oFREvent.target.result;
    };

    $(function() {
        $("input:file").change(function (){
            var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
            var oFile = input.files[0];
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);  
            });
    });

</script>
```

*Update:*

The problem is: if I try to open a new page passing the Data Image string as a parameter in the URL (with "?"). The new page will show the 404 error that I mentioned, because the string is too long.

Comment: Use POST instead of GET …

Comment: @CBroe, where exactly? Thanks

Comment: Well there where you are trying to pass the data to the server, and say that now you are running into the limits of using GET …

Comment: where is the part of code that gives you 404?

Comment: @MilinduSanojKumarage, if I take that Data Image string and add to the new page URL as a param (with "?") and open the page, the new page will show that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make work with php (considering that I didn't want to work with php) and html forms (methods get and post)... So I used the jQuery library called "[jQuery Storage](http://yckart.github.io/jquery.storage.js/)".

It was easy, on the page that I select the image you shoud use:

```
$.sessionStorage([key],[value]);
```

So, was like that:

```
$.sessionStorage('chosenImg', document.getElementById("photoImg").src);
```

And in the new page, to get the value, just add in the code:

```
$.sessionStorage('chosenImg');
```

Of course, I had to download de .js library from the website and add the line below on both html pages:

```
<script src="jquery.storage.js"></script>
```

The only inconvenient it is a little heavy for mobile, but was the only way I found...

That is it! Thanks everyone!

[dataimage](/questions/tagged/dataimage) [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) [data](/questions/tagged/data) [image](/questions/tagged/image)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your form to

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="[Page2 URL]">
    <input id="filePic" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture />    
</form>
```

where [Page2 URL] is the URL for page to receive the image uploaded.

And JavaScript to

```
oFReader = new FileReader();

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {     
    var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
    screenHeight = screenHeight - 220;

    var img = $('#fotoImg');
    img.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result);

    img.css( { height : screenHeight, visibility: 'visible' });
    $("#stringImg").text( "Data Image: " + oFREvent.target.result);
    $('#form1').submit();
};

$(function() {
    $("input:file").change(function (){
        var oFile = this.files[0];
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
    });
});
```

Comment: But this will not create URL characters either? How I can access the values from the new page? Well, I tried that way, but I couldn't  make work... Thanks!

Comment: please post sample code to understand the issue better.. html/js

Comment: I posted on the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/8u426/. I'm trying to pass the data image string to another page, but I can't with the method get on the form, because of the size of the string... I'm still trying with the post method, but no success yet...